# I want to add multiple products in Add to cart in Java spring boot + thymleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, collections, thymeleaf

I want to add multiple products in my add to cart page but right now I'm only able to add one product only. But I want something like if I added one product then that product is there is add to cart and user can add another product in the same cart.

See my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/addtocart")
    public ModelAndView addToCart(@RequestParam(value ="prodId") int prodId, HttpSession session) {
        
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        
        List<Product> cart= new ArrayList<Product>();
        Product prod = new Product();
        
        
        prod = pRepo.findById(prodId).get();
        
          int pId = prod.getProdId(); 
          session.setAttribute("cartInfo", cart);
          session.setAttribute("pId", pId);
    
        cart.add(prod);
        
        model.addObject("products", cart);
        model.setViewName("addtocart");
        return model;
    }
```

Thymleaf code:

```
<div>
      <table>   
          <tr th:each="product: ${products}">

              <div class="card" style="align-items: center;">
               <img th:src="@{'/uploads/' + ${product.filename}}" alt="product name" width="150" height="150" />
                <h2 th:text="${product.prodName}"></h2>
                <p th:text="${product.prodDesc}" />
                <p th:text=" '₹ '+ ${product.price}" />
                <form name="myForm" th:action="@{/addtocart}" th:object="${total}" method="post">
                <label class="label">Quantity <input class="inputclass" style="align-items: center;" type="Number" name="quant" th:value="${quanti}" required="required" /></label>
                <span><p th:text=" 'Sub Total ₹ '+ ${total}"></p></span>
               <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" value="Update"></p><br />
               </form>
               
             <div>
                <p><a th:href="@{|/removeproduct?prodId=${product.prodId}|}">Remove Product</a></p><br />
                <p><a th:href="@{|/product|}">Continue Shopping</a></p><br />
            </div>
               
              </div>
              <br />
           </tr> 
      </table>
    </div>
```

Please help I'm new to this and right now after solving trying n number of times now I'm confused.

Comment: You are creating new List over and over, if you want to have access to the same cart take it out from addToCart method and initialize it as a static. Anyway feel like you got bad approach, cart should be handle on front-end. I mean you are adding to cart product on front-end and back-end should only check if it's possible. When you are finish you are sending List of Products.

Comment: @Borsuk can you please help me the correct way of doing so, I'm literally confused. can you please help me with code? if possible please

Comment: Yea, sure there's a quick example: https://pastebin.pl/view/aed24c4e
Note: that is example and you now need to change return type etc. to your demand

Comment: @Borsuk I have made changes as you suggested, but what I want is different users have added different products but for all log in the same product is showing. how that can be done?

Comment: Yea, it's showing everyone the same cart because it is static. If you want to get different cart for every user i see two choice. First make new table in your database where foreign key will be a ID of user, The second one and witch i prefer, don't storage cart on server side, use Java Script or something else on client side for storage products. And only when user click SUBMIT send whole list of product and validate the order :)

Comment: @borsuk okay i got your point and i also prefer second option as best option but how do i implement this second option could you please help me?? Since i have customer entity for customer details and product entity for product details. If you want to know more i will give answer. Please if possible please help me to get my project done. Please

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Product> cart= new ArrayList<Product>();
cart.add(prod);
```

You are adding one product in the cart and displaying the same in tempate. you could instead maintain these products for that user in db. and display all the products for that user finally.

Comment: How to do that can you please help me?